# Secure connection from S3 to EC2 on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm sure this is a fairly simple question regarding EC2 and S3 on AWS.

I have a static website hosted on S3 which connects to a MongoDB server on an EC2 instance which I want to secure. Currently it's open to all of the internet 0.0.0.0/0 on port 27017, which is the MDB default. I want to restrict the inbound traffic to only requests from the S3 static web site however for security reasons. Apparently S3 does not supply fixed addresses which is causing a problem.

My only thought was to open the port to all IP ranges for the S3 region I am in. This doc on AWS explains how to find these. Although they are subject to change without notice.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

Would this be the way to proceed or am I missing something obvious here. Another way to assign an IP to S3 perhaps?

Comment: isnt it possible to set inbound rules by Domain name and not IP?

Comment: or assign a static IP to S3 .

Comment: Maybe using a VPC Endpoint, read this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/)

Comment: **You are missunderstanding something very significant.** 
When you have a static site hosted on S3 (or any other service providing static hosting) your other resources -- MongoDB in this case -- will **never** see the requests come from S3 (the static web server) IPs. They come from the web browser viewing the site.  It is impossible to use IP addresses or domain names to control this access, because the requests come directly from the browser.  This is not related to S3 or AWS.  It's how web sites work when the active content runs on the browser.  You have a design problem.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot That is interesting. I am not a web developer so that is useful to know. How would I go about securing the EC2 server if not though restricting the inbound rules?

Comment: The problem is that you need to secure the server yet allow anyone to access a resource from it.  The topic becomes rather broad, here, depending in part on how the resource (mongo) is being used and the specific motivation for wanting to restrict it, but the general idea is a trusted middle entity that won't send anything to the inner resource that its rules don't allow.  Databases are typically exposed indirectly, via an API layer (like AWS API Gateway, often combined with AWS Lambda).

Answer (score 1):

S3 is a storage service, not a compute service so it cannot make a request to your MongoDB. When S3 serves static webpages, your browser will render it and when a user clicks on a link to connect to your MongoDB, the **request goes to MongoDB from the user's computer**.

So MongoDB sees the request coming from the user's IP. Since you do not know where the user is coming from (or the IP range), you have no choice but to listen to traffic from any IP.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to allow only for your s3 hosted site to access your DB inside the ec2 since s3 does not offer an IP address for you.

So its better to try an alternative solution such as instead of directly access DB, proxy through a https service inside your ec2 and restrict the inbound traffic for your mondo db port

Answer (score 0):

s3 wont request your mongodb server on ec2 instance . From my understanding your js files in browser would request the mongodb running on  ec2 instance . In that case you have to add message headers in the mongodb configuration files to allow **CORS** .

CORS: [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)